# Sending variable through href

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass a variable through an href url on my View, and have the Controller function query based on those variables. Here is code to get  a better idea.

```
     @foreach ($totalCount as $id => $name) {{-- id is the admin id --}}
    <?php
      $admin_id = $id;
    ?>
    @foreach($name as $n => $status)  {{-- $n is the name, $status is array of the counts --}}
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{$n}}
        <br>
        <a href="#">Closed</a>
      </td>
          <td><a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=2&id={{{$admin_id}}}">{{ isset($status[2]) ? $status[2] : 0 }}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=1&id={{{$admin_id}}}">{{ isset($status[1]) ? $status[1] : 0 }}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=3&id={{{$admin_id}}}">{{ isset($status[3]) ? $status[3] : 0 }}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=4&id={{{$admin_id}}}">{{ isset($status[4]) ? $status[4] : 0 }}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=5&id={{{$admin_id}}}">{{ isset($status[5]) ? $status[5] : 0 }}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=6&id={{{$admin_id}}}">{{ isset($status[6]) ? $status[6] : 0 }}</a></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
  @endforeach
```

As you can see, I am getting that $id from my data structure and inputting it into $admin_id so I can use it. I take that admin id and place it into the href url so my controller can work with it and query properly.

Here is code from my controller:

```
     public function index()
  {
    $query = AdvertiserApplication::with('admin');
    $status = Input::get('status');
    $id = Input::get('admin_id');
    dd($id);

    if(!empty($id)) {
      $query->where('assigned_to', '=', $id);
    }
    if (!empty($status) || $status === '0')
      $query->where('staus', '=', $status);



    $applications = $query->get();

    return View::make('admin.advertisers.application_list', ['applications' => $applications, 'admin_id' => AuthAdmin::admin(false)]);
  }
```

What I am doing here is querying the whole table if $id and $status empty. (By the way status comes from a drop down table on the application list View.) The problem I am having is that the $id input is not working, it is coming in NULL. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Should be**

```
Input::get('id');
```

**Instead of**

```
Input::get('admin_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add $id as parameter of index function.

When variable is sent through href it is not element of GET/POST array.

So your function will lool like this:

```
public function index($id)
{
$query =      AdvertiserApplication::with('admin');
$status = Input::get('status');
// $id = Input::get('admin_id');
// dd($id);

if(!empty($id)) {
  $query->where('assigned_to', '=', $id);
}
if (!empty($status) || $status === '0')
  $query->where('staus', '=', $status);



$applications = $query->get();

return View::make('admin.advertisers.application_list', ['applications' => $applications, 'admin_id' => AuthAdmin::admin(false)]);
```

}